# Initializing two-dimensional JPanel arrays using a for loop

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I'm relatively new to java and i'm trying to do an assignment for school. In my assignment i'm supposed to make a GUI program that makes a 8 by 8 red and black colored checkerboard. The only problem (so far) that i'm having is initializing a two-dimensional array of JPanels. i'm getting this error when using eclipse:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
```

This doesn't give an error until i try to run the code. It says the error is occurring in the body of this for loop:

```
JPanel[][] panel = new JPanel[7][7];

for (int i = 0; i <= panel.length; i++){
panel[i][0] = new JPanel();
panel[i][1] = new JPanel();
panel[i][2] = new JPanel();
panel[i][3] = new JPanel();
panel[i][4] = new JPanel();
panel[i][5] = new JPanel();
panel[i][6] = new JPanel();
panel[i][7] = new JPanel();
}
```

This does work if i don't use a for loop but i *really* don't want to put in 64 different statements do do this. I double checked and the panel.length *does* give the value 7 (which is what i wanted) and did not work even when i physically put in 7. I don't have any syntax error is my code, but i still get the error. Is there some other way i should go about doing this? Thanks in advance. Remember i'm new to this.

Comment: Change `i <= panel.length` to `i < panel.length`. And you could probably use a nested loop for this. Note that arrays are zero-indexed so the last element at a 7-length array would be at the 6th index.

Comment: i'm new to this and i should probably know what a nested loop is but i don't and if i use 'i < panel.length' i'll get the same error, cause it would be the same as 'i < 7', or so eclipse says, but i want it to go from 0 to 7 inclusive so i get 8. Thanks for answering anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

1. A checkboard is 8×8, so you really want `panel.length` to be 8, no?
2. A standard `for` loop uses `<` for the test, not `<=`.
3. If you use two *nested* loops, you don't need to repeat `new JPanel()` 8 times.

Result:

```
JPanel[][] panel = new JPanel[8][8];

for (int i = 0; i < panel.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < panel[i].length; j++) {
        panel[i][j] = new JPanel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> *"make a GUI program that makes a 8 by 8 red and black colored checkerboard. The only problem (so far) that i'm having is initializing a two-dimensional array of JPanels."*.

If all you need to do is make the board, with no other conditions, why not just use a `GridLayout`

```
 JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8, 8));

 for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++){
     JPanel panel = new JPanel();
     // alternate background colors with a predefined boolean and an if
     mainPanel.add(panel);
 }
```